# Reducing a flame on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, orach-chaim, fire-burning, ochel-nefesh

Accordion to Halacha, is it permissible for Jews to reduce the strength of a flame on Yom Tov? For example, if a Jew is cooking something on a gas stove, is it permitted for them to reduce the power of the flame so their food doesn’t burn, or not?

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2017/05/30/blech-and-lowering-a-fire-on-yom-tov/